# actionscript 3: border for label of progressbar not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

Is there anyone know how to make border for label of progress bar in action script 3? I tried to setStyle("borderColor",#ff0000) but it's not success.

Answer (score 0):

In the example code of the [Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ProgressBar.html) I see that styles are initialized with the notation `0xAAB3B3`.

I would suggest to change the color in your function to `0xff0000`.

The `0x` means that it's a Hexadecimal number.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not success.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the border color of the label of a [`mx.controls.ProgressBar`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ProgressBar.html) component using `mx.core.mx_internal` like this :

```
progress_bar.mx_internal::_labelField.border = true;
progress_bar.mx_internal::_labelField.borderColor = 0x0000ff;
```

Hope that can help.